# IOS: Resize View Using CGAffineTransform

Tags: ios, cgaffinetransform

I can't get a CGAffineTransform transformation to expand a view in a table cell and cannot understand why.

Can anyone see what is wrong.  Here is my code:

```
UIView* resizedView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetMaxX(view.frame), CGRectGetMaxY(view.frame))];
        [resizedView addSubview:view];
        [cell addSubview:view];

        CGSize sizeDifference = CGSizeMake(resizedView.frame.size.width - view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height - view.frame.size.height);
            NSLog(@"width = %f, height = %f", sizeDifference.width, sizeDifference.height);

        CGSize transformRatio = CGSizeMake(resizedView.frame.size.width / view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height / view.frame.size.height);

        //  Original transform
        CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;

        //  Scale custom view so image will fill entire cell
        transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, transformRatio.width, transformRatio.height);

        //  Move custom view so the old vie's top left aligns with the cell's top left
        transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, -sizeDifference.width / 2.0, -sizeDifference.height / 2.0);

        [resizedView setTransform:transform];
```

The view remains exactly the same.  Would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Why would you use a transform to resize an image view? Why not just resize the image view?

Comment: How would I resize the image view without cgaffinetransform?

Comment: To be clear, the image is in a view.  Right now I can't get either the image or the view to change size.  Ideally, I'd like a solution that works for any view.  Removed the word image from question.

Comment: "How would I resize the image view without cgaffinetransform" The same as how you resize _any_ view — setting its `frame` (or its `frame.size`). (However, if the view is already sized by autolayout constraints, then you would do it by changing the view's constraints.)